# Powershell how to update AD Address 2 lines

Tags: csv, powershell

Happy Tuesday, I have a csv file that has 2 address columns, one for street address and the other for say the suite, basically 2 lines. This syntax doesn't appear to be the way to go. Is there a better way? thx!

```
Set-ADUser -identity $User -Replace @{streetAddress = ("+$Row.'Location Address'+"`r`"+$Row.'Location Address Line 2'+"); l = $Row.'Location City'; postalcode = $Row.'Location Zip'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line probably doesn't do what you want.

```
"+$Row.'Location Address'+"`r`"+$Row.'Location Address Line 2'+"
```

It looks like you want to build up a string from multiple variables, but you forgot a `"` at the beginning, so `"+$Row.'Location Address'+"` is a string, and then `` `r` `` is outside the string, causing a syntax error.

There are three ways to build a string from variables in PowerShell.  The first is what I'll call the JavaScript way, concatenating strings as you go.  This is supported, but not really recommended.

```
"" + $Row.'Location Address' + "`r`n" + $Row.'Location Address Line 2'
```

The second is the .NET way, where you use a Format string and the `-f` operator.

```
"{0}`r`n{1}" -f ($Row.'Location Address', $Row.'Location Address Line 2')
```

The third is to have PowerShell parse variables inside your string using `$(expr)` syntax

```
"$($Row.'Location Address')`r`n$($Row.'Location Address Line 2')"
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan! Hope this helps others with a similar issue. :)